# How to force focus on a Nebular Select element?

Tags: angular, autocomplete, nebular

I'm using a `nb-autocomplete` component, and after selecting a value I need to keep focus on the element. Everything I've tried so far does not work:

Here's my HTML:

```
<input
type="text"
nbInput
placeholder="Destinations"
autocomplete="off"
(input)="onDestinationsChange(i)"
id="autocomplete-{{ i }}"
[nbAutocomplete]="destination"
/>
<nb-autocomplete
#destination
(selectedChange)="onDestinationSelectedChange($event, i)"
>
    <nb-option
        *ngFor="let autocompleteDestination of autocompleteDestinations$ | async"
        [value]="autocompleteDestination"
    >
        {{ autocompleteDestination?.name }}
    </nb-option>
</nb-autocomplete>
```

And here are my attempts within the `onDestinationSelectedChange()` of the service:

```
const destinationElem = (document.getElementById(`autocomplete-${itineraryIndex}`) as HTMLInputElement);
destinationElem.focus();
```

**result: nothing happens, even with chrome devtools closed***

My other attempt was using a NativeElement and calling `focus()` on that:

```
@ViewChild('autocomplete-0', {static: false}) inputEl:ElementRef;
this.inputEl.nativeElement.focus()
```

But this returns `native element undefined`

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

`this.inputEl['hostRef'].nativeElement.focus();`

Answer (score 0):

There is a property for it: `focusInputOnValueChange`

Here is the [documentation](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/autocomplete/api#nbautocompletedirective)